# Web Reference appending 'call' before method name

Tags: vb.net, web-services, asmx

I have a web service set up in IIS that works. I can call it from the browser and it loads properly - I see my method.

I have a website where I tried to add a web reference. I searched for web services on the local machine and my service came up. I was even able to find my method by clicking on the service.

But for some reason, after I add the reference, the method is not available. I created an instance of the service, but when I try to call the method I get an error - 'method' is not a member of 'service'. I checked the reference.vb and I see that the reference appended the word 'call' to the beginning of my method name so it is now calluploadBurnData(parameters). Using this method name works, but why is 'call' appended?? I have many web references in this project and none of them had this issue.

Comment: Why a Web Reference instead of a Service Reference? Web References use the ASMX technology. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Because I am not creating the service - it is an existing web service that I am upgrading from .net 1.1 to .net 4.0. I had no problem with any of the other services - only ran into an issue with this one. I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but the method has the same name as the class. Can that be the issue?

Comment: Apparently that is the issue - the method name is the same as the class name. When I took out the last letter from the method name (uploadBurnDat) all worked fine.

Comment: FYI, I wasn't suggesting that you upgrade the service. I only meant that you should use service references and not web references.

Comment: I understand, but in order to use service references, wouldn't I need to convert my asmx services to WCF services?

Comment: No. Service reference is the replacement for web reference. You can use it for any kind of service, the same way you can use web reference for Java services, for instance.